# Obtener promedio de un arreglo mediante recursividad en java

Tags: java

Del siguiente arreglo quiero sacar el promedio usando recursividad
`int[] arreglo ={1,5,7,8,5,3,5,8,6,1,2,4,6,8,1,4,6,9,7,6,4,3,8,2}`

No soy muy bueno usando recursividad en java. Alguien que me ayude.

Esto es lo que he hecho, sacar la sumatoria del arreglo:

```
 static int Promedio (int n[], int pos){
 if(pos<n.length){
     return n[pos] + Promedio(n,pos+1); 
 }
 return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado.

Comment: Ya agregue lo que tengo hecho

Comment: la funcion esta bien.. pero no esta calculando el promedio en ningun caso.. empieza por preguntarte, como se calcula el promedio?

Comment: La recursividad ya la tienes para la suma. Solo faltaría, ahora, convertirla en una que haga un promedio. Estás cerca!.

Answer (score 2):

Una posible solución, entregando un resultado entero, basada en el código que ya tienes, es:

```
static int Promedio (int n[], int pos) {
  if (pos == 0) {
    return (n[pos] + Promedio(n, pos+1)) / n.length; 
  } 
  if(pos < n.length) {
    return n[pos] + Promedio(n, pos+1); 
  } 
  return 0; 
}
```

OJO, que usualmente el promedio es un número de coma flotante, incluso si los números a promediar son enteros.

Mi sugerencia, sin embargo, es que implementes una función recursiva `suma` y el promedio sea una función separada (no recursiva). Es solo por tema de que cada función tenga un nombre apropiado para la operación que realiza, y para todos los elementos, excepto el primero, la función en realidad está sumando.

Quedaría algo así:

```
static int Suma(int [n], int pos) {
  if(pos < n.length) {
    return n[pos] + Suma(n, pos + 1); 
  } 
  return 0; 
}

static int Promedio (int n[]) {
  return Suma(n, 0) / n.length; 
}
```

Comment: En la evaluación de tu primer if del método Promedio, debería ser **if (pos == 0)**

Comment: Oh, si, gracias, edité la respuesta para que quede correcta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

A continuación una solución de lo que requieres, tomando como base lo que intentaste:

```
public class prueba {

    private static int suma = 0;

    public static void main (String [ ] args) {
        int array[] = { 1,5,7,8,5,3,5,8,6,1,2,4,6,8,1,4,6,9,7,6,4,3,8,2 };
        System.out.println(obtenerPromedio(array, 0)); // 0 es la posición inicial del Array
    }

    public static float obtenerPromedio(int n[], int pos){
        if(pos < n.length) {
            suma = suma + n[pos];
            obtenerPromedio(n, pos + 1);
        }
        return (float)suma/ (float)n.length;
    }
}
```

El resultado al ejecutar el código anterior es **4.9583335**, por lo siguiente:

- Suma de los elementos del Array = **119**
- Número de elementos en el Array = **24**
- Resultado División(Promedio): 119/24 = **4.9583335**

> Nota: se cambió el tipo de dato que retorna la función
>   **obtenerPromedio()** de `int` a `float` para que se obtenga los decimales de la división.